# installing and running mongodb in codeanywhere

Tags: mongodb

i used this code:

```
$ mkdir data
$ echo 'mongod --bind_ip=$0.0.0.0 --dbpath=data --nojournal  "$@"' > mongod
$ chmod a+x mongod
```

i have made a file called mongodb that contains this:

```
​ mongod --bind_ip=$0.0.0.0 --dbpath=data --nojournal  "$@"
```

but when i run

```
./mongod
```

i get this and it doesn't work:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9224.png

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using one of the recent versions of Mongo.
 Try this:
Step1- Make a directory, say database, its path being `/home/cabox/database`
Step2- In the same level as the directory database, create a file named mongod.log, by using `touch /home/cabox/mongod.log`
Step3- Create a configuration file for our database, mongod.conf using
    `touch /home/cabox/mongod.conf`
Step4- Now open this file using vi and put following lines in it

```
systemLog:                                                                                                
  destination: file                                                                                       
  path: "/home/cabox/mongod.log"                                                                          
  logAppend: true                                                                                         
processManagement:                                                                                        
  fork: true                                                                                              
storage:                                                                                                  
  dbPath: "/home/cabox/database"                                                                          
  journal:                                                                                                
    enabled: true                                                                                         
  engine: "mmapv1"                                                                                        
  mmapv1:                                                                                                 
    smallFiles: true                                                                                      
net:                                                                                                      
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
```

Step5- Save this file and start mongod by running:
 mongod --config /home/cabox/mongod.conf
Step6- Start the shell: mongo

Hopefully everything should be working fine by now. The problem with your method was that mongod was using wired Tiger storage engine by default, which causes space related problems in containers like codeanywhere which have a small disk size.

P.S - In the conf file, make sure you indent using spaces and not tabs.
You can shutdown the server by using:

  `mongo --eval "db.getSiblingDB('admin').shutdownServer()"`

To check whether it has been successfully started or shutdown:
`netstat -ntulp|grep 27017`